# How to convert ascii character in string to character in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have an input button :

```
   <input type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right" id="doneBtn" value="@Resource.Add (0) @Resource.productsToCampaign" />
```

@Resource.Add and @Resource.productsToCampaign is dynamicly loaded depends on which language a user have chosen.

The problem is that when i want to update (0) to some number depends on how many items user chooses, @Resource.Add in one language have some special character which encodes to ø when i update value of the button.

what happends when user updates item list :

```
    var add = '\@Resource.Add';
$("#doneBtn").val(add + '(' + temporarySelectedItems.length + ')' + '@Resource.productsToCampaign');
```

charcode at will not work, because strings in different languages are not same length

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

If @Resource.Add does not contain '(', I would use indexof('(') to find the start position of the number.